In OpenSearch query, I want to use script inside the must query
I need to verify whether a candidate's total experience is zero before returning any associated documents or data. Conversely, if the total experience is not zero, I want to retrieve the documents. Despite my attempts to access this information using various parameters such as params._source.total_experiences, ctx._source.total_experiences, and doc['total_experiences'], none of these methods have yielded the desired results. It seems that the mechanism to retrieve this data is not functioning correctly in any of these scenarios. Hence, I seek alternative solutions to effectively ascertain and act upon the total experience value as per the specified criteria.
Here is my query
GET enriched_scraped_profiles/_search
{
  "_source": true,
  "size": 2000, 
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "experiences.industry": "Banking"
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": {
        "script": {
          "script": {
            "lang": "painless",
            "source": """
                if (params['_source']['total_experiences'] != 0) {
                  return true;
                }
              return false;
            """
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

But I got this error:
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "script_exception",
        "reason": "runtime error",
        "script_stack": [
          "if (params['_source']['total_experiences'] != 0) {\n                  ",
          "          ^---- HERE"
        ],
        "script": " ...",
        "lang": "painless",
        "position": {
          "offset": 27,
          "start": 17,
          "end": 86
        }
      }
    ],
    "type": "search_phase_execution_exception",
    "reason": "all shards failed",
    "phase": "query",
    "grouped": true,
    "failed_shards": [
      {
        "shard": 0,
        "index": "enriched_scraped_profiles",
        "node": "je5hZrUORgWk9EEmuHQ9rQ",
        "reason": {
          "type": "script_exception",
          "reason": "runtime error",
          "script_stack": [
            "if (params['_source']['total_experiences'] != 0) {\n                  ",
            "          ^---- HERE"
          ],
          "script": " ...",
          "lang": "painless",
          "position": {
            "offset": 27,
            "start": 17,
            "end": 86
          },
          "caused_by": {
            "type": "null_pointer_exception",
            "reason": "Cannot invoke \"Object.getClass()\" because \"callArgs[0]\" is null"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "status": 400
}

Here is document
{
  "_index": "enriched_scraped_profiles",
  "_id": "mohammed-alyousef-mkt",
  "_score": 21.133842,
  "_source": {
    "country": "SA",
    "accomplishment_patents": [
      
    ],
    "occupation": "Digital Content Officer at Takamol Holding",
    "education": [
      {
        "starts_at": {
          "month": 1,
          "year": 2017,
          "day": 1
        },
        "degree_name": "Bachelor ",
        "school": "King Saud University",
        "logo_url": "https://media.licdn.com/dms/image/C560BAQGsF4tX875gZw/company-logo_400_400/0/1631357058699?e=1714003200&v=beta&t=Ik1pHNTQPvtRPwibnqchGGVHEKP5PZB_XyaHpQ-P6sU",
        "grade": null,
        "activities_and_societies": null,
        "description": null,
        "ends_at": {
          "month": 12,
          "year": 2021,
          "day": 31
        },
        "school_linkedin_profile_url": null,
        "field_of_study": "marketing"
      }
    ],
    "birth_date": null,
    "total_experiences": 2.48,
    "recommendations": [
      
    ],
    "skills": [
      "Twitter Ads",
      "Twitter Marketing",
      "Tiktok Marketing",
      "Snapchat Marketing",
      "Meta Marketing",
      "Google Ads",
      "الإدارة",
      "Digital Marketing",
      "Analytical Skills",
      "تسويق المنتجات",
      "Strategy",
      "Microsoft Excel",
      "Microsoft Office",
      "Teamwork",
      "Communication",
      "Hootsuite"
    ],
    "personal_numbers": [
      
    ],
    "state": null,
    "volunteer_work": [
      
    ],
    "profile_pic_url": "https://media.licdn.com/dms/image/D4D03AQEDGKNsFHwUEQ/profile-displayphoto-shrink_800_800/0/1701794487213?e=1711584000&v=beta&t=5ejzAgm5kocP07McKbs4h7_kWlT6tYIxWDbmjChhU2A",
    "connections": null,
    "candidate_gender": "Male",
    "last_updated": "24-01-2024",
    "similarly_named_profiles": [
      
    ],
    "accomplishment_courses": [
      
    ],
    "experiences": [
      {
        "starts_at": {
          "month": 2,
          "year": 2022,
          "day": 1
        },
        "logo_url": "https://media.licdn.com/dms/image/C4E0BAQEbKUtqr6OQhQ/company-logo_400_400/0/1645452491805/takamolholding_logo?e=1714003200&v=beta&t=v3C3LiMBXJiUqfxv7JYQdD_hjBGfv0q6I0jvb_FBLUo",
        "company_linkedin_profile_url": "https://www.linkedin.com/company/takamolholding/",
        "total_experience_months": 23,
        "description": null,
        "company": "Takamol Holding",
        "location": "Riyadh, Saudi Arabia",
        "ends_at": {
          "month": 12,
          "year": 2023,
          "day": 31
        },
        "title": "Digital Content Officer"
      },
      {
        "starts_at": {
          "month": 11,
          "year": 2021,
          "day": 1
        },
        "logo_url": "https://media.licdn.com/dms/image/C4E0BAQEbKUtqr6OQhQ/company-logo_400_400/0/1645452491805/takamolholding_logo?e=1714003200&v=beta&t=v3C3LiMBXJiUqfxv7JYQdD_hjBGfv0q6I0jvb_FBLUo",
        "company_linkedin_profile_url": "https://www.linkedin.com/company/takamolholding/",
        "total_experience_months": 4,
        "description": null,
        "company": "Takamol Holding",
        "location": "Saudi Arabia",
        "ends_at": {
          "month": 2,
          "year": 2022,
          "day": 28
        },
        "title": "Digital Marketing Intern"
      },
      {
        "starts_at": {
          "month": 9,
          "year": 2021,
          "day": 1
        },
        "logo_url": "https://media.licdn.com/dms/image/C4E0BAQEbKUtqr6OQhQ/company-logo_400_400/0/1645452491805/takamolholding_logo?e=1714003200&v=beta&t=v3C3LiMBXJiUqfxv7JYQdD_hjBGfv0q6I0jvb_FBLUo",
        "company_linkedin_profile_url": "https://www.linkedin.com/company/takamolholding/",
        "total_experience_months": 3,
        "description": null,
        "company": "Takamol Holding",
        "location": "Riyadh, Saudi Arabia",
        "ends_at": {
          "month": 11,
          "year": 2021,
          "day": 30
        },
        "title": "Internship Trainee"
      }
    ],
    "country_full_name": "Saudi Arabia",
    "full_name": "Mohammed Alyousef",
    "accomplishment_organisations": [
      
    ],
    "status": "ready for match",
    "note": "",
    "gender": "Male",
    "activity": [
      {
        "note": "",
        "status_id": 1,
        "stage": "screening",
        "status_change_time": "04-16-2024 13:18",
        "user_id": "Nawaf Alageel",
        "status": "not contacted"
      },
      {
        "note": "test",
        "status_id": 1,
        "stage": "screening",
        "status_change_time": "04-16-2024 13:18",
        "user_id": "Nawaf Alageel",
        "status": "not contacted"
      },
      {
        "note": "ما يبغى سيلز",
        "stage": "screening",
        "status_change_time": "04-16-2024 13:20",
        "user_id": "Nawaf Alageel",
        "status": "contacted"
      },
      {
        "note": "",
        "stage": "screening",
        "status_change_time": "04-16-2024 13:22",
        "user_id": "Nawaf Alageel",
        "status": "ready for match"
      }
    ],
    "city": "Riyadh Region",
    "Response Time": 97.1856210231781,
    "people_also_viewed": [
      {
        "summary": "Creative Copywriter | social media| Marketing Communication",
        "link": "https://www.linkedin.com/in/ruba-al-jumah-dmi-0561a61b0",
        "name": "Ruba   Al Jumah, DMI",
        "location": null
      },
      {
        "summary": "Digital Marketing| Social Media| Management |Sr.Project Manager at tact digital communication",
        "link": "https://www.linkedin.com/in/meshal-almeshkhas-979485187",
        "name": "Meshal AlMeshkhas",
        "location": null
      },
      {
        "summary": "Digital Marketing | Social Media Management & Ads | Media buying",
        "link": "https://www.linkedin.com/in/ali-alhudaithy-312957135",
        "name": "Ali Alhudaithy",
        "location": null
      },
      {
        "summary": "Communications | PR | Digital Media | Marketing | Corporate Identity & Branding",
        "link": "https://www.linkedin.com/in/muhammad-al-sulami",
        "name": "Mohammad Alsulami",
        "location": null
      },
      {
        "summary": "Media Communications Specialist",
        "link": "https://www.linkedin.com/in/lina-abuqayyan",
        "name": "Lina Abuqayyan",
        "location": null
      },
      {
        "summary": "Digital Marketing | Strategy | Paid ads | Social media",
        "link": "https://www.linkedin.com/in/sarah-binshuhayl-a08a20163",
        "name": "Sarah Binshuhayl ",
        "location": null
      },
      {
        "summary": "Marketing | Communication | Digital Marketing |copywriting | Campaigns management",
        "link": "https://www.linkedin.com/in/nawaf-alshehri443",
        "name": "Nawaf Alshehri ",
        "location": null
      },
      {
        "summary": "Data Analyst | Digital Marketing | Social Media Management | Campaigns | Project Management",
        "link": "https://www.linkedin.com/in/mona-alfozan-590502198",
        "name": "Mona Alfozan",
        "location": null
      },
      {
        "summary": "Digital Marketing | Branding | Communications",
        "link": "https://www.linkedin.com/in/afnan-al-mutairi",
        "name": "Afnan Almutairi",
        "location": null
      },
      {
        "summary": "Advertising Campaigns | Marketing | Communication | Marketer | Engagement Media Channel | Marketing Strategy | Digital Marketing",
        "link": "https://www.linkedin.com/in/abdullah-bin-jughayman-043536155",
        "name": "Abdullah Bin jughayman",
        "location": null
      }
    ],
    "inferred_salary": null,
    "background_cover_image_url": null,
    "industry": null,
    "follower_count": 658,
    "Source": "Proxycurl",
    "profile_link_url": "https://www.linkedin.com/in/mohammed-alyousef-mkt",
    "total_experience": 2.48,
    "accomplishment_publications": [
      
    ],
    "extra": null,
    "headline": "Digital Marketer | Social Media ",
    "public_identifier": "mohammed-alyousef-mkt",
    "first_name": "Mohammed",
    "summary": "A passionate and dedicated individual with a strong theoretical and practical knowledge in Marketing, looking forward to pursue an exciting new career that will broaden my horizons and increase my knowledge in the various fields of Digital Marketing. ",
    "languages": [
      
    ],
    "groups": [
      
    ],
    "last_name": "Alyousef",
    "certifications": [
      
    ],
    "stage": "screening",
    "activities": [
      
    ],
    "personal_emails": [
      
    ],
    "accomplishment_test_scores": [
      
    ],
    "interests": [
      
    ],
    "articles": [
      
    ],
    "accomplishment_projects": [
      
    ],
    "accomplishment_honors_awards": [
      
    ]
  }
}


Why do you really want to use script? Why not simply filter on total experience field?

Right, but We have experienced an array of objects so I want to check total_months_experiences for that I want to use a script.

@SaunakSurani can you share the mapping and a sample document from your index

Thanks for sharing, you should use doc['field'].value instead of params[]. I'm sharing the full example as an answer

In the script query, you should use doc['field'].value instead of params[].
Here is the working version:
PUT test_enriched_scraped_profiles/_doc/1
{
  "total_experiences": 5
}

GET test_enriched_scraped_profiles/_search
{
  "size": 2000, 
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "script": {
          "script": {
            "lang": "painless",
            "source": """
                if (doc['total_experiences'].value != 0) {
                  return true;
                }
              return false;
            """
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

Check the following article for the syntax and information: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-script-query.html

"source": """
double totalMonths = 0;
for (def experience : doc['experiences'].value) {
if (experience.containsKey('starts_at') && experience['starts_at'] != null &&
experience.containsKey('total_experience_months') && experience['total_experience_months'] != null) {
totalMonths += experience['total_experience_months']
}
}
return totalMonths >= 12 && totalMonths <= 24;
"""
This script not working for the array of objects.

I didn't know who wrote the script you shared. There is no field named experiences. Please don't only copy paste from ChatGPT to here. I can't help you like that.

We have experiences fields as an array of objects.

Your scripts could be replaced with aggregations
Mapping for my example
PUT /enriched_scraped_profiles
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "full_name": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "raw": {
                        "type": "keyword"
                    }
                }
            },
            "experiences": {
                "type": "nested",
                "properties": {
                    "total_experience_months": {
                        "type": "integer"
                    },
                    "industry": {
                        "type": "keyword"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Document for the example
PUT /enriched_scraped_profiles/_bulk
{"create":{"_id":"mohammed-alyousef-mkt"}}
{"full_name":"Mohammed Alyousef","experiences":[{"industry":"Banking","total_experience_months":16},{"industry":"Banking","total_experience_months":4}]}

Your adapted query
GET /enriched_scraped_profiles/_search?filter_path=aggregations
{
    "_source": true,
    "size": 2000,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "nested": {
                        "path": "experiences",
                        "query": {
                            "term": {
                                "experiences.industry": "Banking"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "by_name": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "full_name.raw",
                "size": 10
            },
            "aggs": {
                "inside_experience": {
                    "nested": {
                        "path": "experiences"
                    },
                    "aggs": {
                        "sum_total_experience_months": {
                            "sum": {
                                "field": "experiences.total_experience_months"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                "experience_months_filter": {
                    "bucket_selector": {
                        "buckets_path": {
                            "sumTotalExperinceMonths": "inside_experience>sum_total_experience_months"
                        },
                        "script": """
                            (params.sumTotalExperinceMonths >= 12) && (params.sumTotalExperinceMonths <= 24)
                        """
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

experience_months_filter is a pipeline aggregation with the filter condition
Response
{
    "aggregations" : {
        "by_name" : {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
            "buckets" : [
                {
                    "key" : "Mohammed Alyousef",
                    "doc_count" : 1,
                    "inside_experience" : {
                        "doc_count" : 2,
                        "sum_total_experience_months" : {
                            "value" : 20.0
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}


Thank you, since the experiences field is an array of objects.
